# two colum grid menu for onepage website

Tags: jquery, css, menu, responsive

I want to make a two column grid menu same like the this website http://prepa.4ltrophy.com/. Can someone help me to provide a sample code how to make a responsive menu like that? I'm a complete newbie so don't know where to start. Any help from your side will be greatly appreciated Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
        * {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          font-family: Segoe UI;
        }
        body {
          background-color: #D8D8D8;
        }
        #grid-menu {
          background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.74);
          max-width: 285px;
          list-style-type: none;
          position: fixed;
          left: 0;
          height: 100%;
        }
        #grid-menu li {
          padding: 30px;
          float: left;
          text-align: center;
          display: table;
          width: 80px;
          border: 1px solid #fff;
          height: 20%;
          transition: .3s ease-in;
          cursor: pointer;
        }
        #grid-menu li:hover {
          background-color: #aaa;
        }
        #grid-menu li a {
          color: black;
          text-decoration: none;
          font-size: 20px;
          font-weight: 100;
        }
```

```html
<ul id="grid-menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">About</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Products</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Blog</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">My tab</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">My tab</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">My tab</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">My tab</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">My tab</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thewbmstr, thank you so much for your prompt help my friend. I will try this :)

Comment: Hi thewbmstr, I need a help from you. this is the website i'm working on the two column grid menu. there are 2 issues i'm facing on the demo, 1: In the responsive mode the menu not showing completely, few links hide in the leftside and 2nd when resize the screen the text content going under the menu strip. i uploaded the demo online http://shinedasphotography.com/demo/ Could you please check that and let me know a solution to sort out that issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Keziah, Thanks for your support. Could you please share the above mentioned demo? Thanks in advance